# Still relevant method of embedding images in WP Theme in 2018

Tags: functions, bloginfo

```
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/logo.png"/>
```

Is the above still a relevant method of embedding images in the Wordpress theme or an obsolete?

If obsolete then what will be the correct method?

someone questioned me today that I am not doing it correctly?

Comment: If it works it works

Comment: what was the argument against?

Comment: @rudtek argument was that this technique is outdated.

Comment: Definitely outdated, but as Tom said, it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> someone questioned me today that I am not doing it correctly?

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/logo.png
```

There are 2 possible reasons this could be considered 'incorrect':

- `get_bloginfo` is a very old function that does multiple things, this particular function was replaced by `get_template_directory_uri` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`
- Security! You didn't escape anything! The entire thing should be wrapped in an `esc_url`

Comment: Hi there, You mean like this →  `src="<?php echo esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri()) ?>/img/image.png"`

Comment: `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )` returns `get_template_directory_uri() `. Line 683 of wp-includes/general-template.php.

Answer (score 1):

I still use this :

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
```

Which works fine.

Comment: `get_template_directory_uri()` should be escaped in this context

Answer (score 1):

The main reason it might be considered outdated, based on the specific name you use for the image, is that since 4.5 IIRC there is a customizer setting which allows the user to upload "site image" which is usually used as a logo.

From a more HTML and semantic web point of view, this code is (and always was) wrong as the logo by itself is a meaningless image (which is why you are unlikely to add an alt attribute to it) and therefor it is a decoration which belong to CSS, either in a CSS file, or set as a background image of a link element if you let the user to have some control over it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than using the above functions, there is a function specifically designed for getting the theme's dependencies. By using [`get_theme_file_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_uri/), you can get the URL to any file included in your theme's folder.

Here's an example:

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url ( get_theme_file_uri( 'images/logo.png' ) ); ?>"/>
```

It will automatically search for `logo.png` and return it's URI if it exists. This function uses `get_template_directory_uri` internally.

Comment: Thanks, you said: "It will automatically search for logo.png" that means even if the path we specified is not correct('images/logo.png', for example) then also if it finds logo.png somewhere else in the theme it will generate a URL.